# What is the best way to find all possible paths between two nodes in large networks scale?

Tags: scalability, graph-algorithm

I wonder that what is the best way to find all possible paths from a source to a destination in a very large network scale (in a network matrix), i.e. 5000 nodes. I have used this [function](https://github.com/kakearney/pathbetweennodes-pkg/blob/master/pathbetweennodes/pathbetweennodes.m) that is implemented using stacks, but its limit seems about 60 nodes and it can't retrieve the paths for a 200-node network. In another approach, DFS (depth-first search) could be one of the options but this algorithm also uses stack, so I am afraid of its scalability. Thus, do we have any efficient way for finding all paths between two given nodes in such a large network?

Comment: If you literally mean all paths -- you are going to run into a combinatorial explosion long before you get to 5000 nodes, unless you have a graph with very few edges

Comment: Yes, instead of finding all possible paths, it could find all shortest paths, so it becomes more realistic and feasible. In addition, the graph could be a complete one.

Comment: It *could* be more feasible, but it is easy enough to come up with examples of graphs which have just 100 nodes but are such that the number of shortest paths between any two nodes is infeasibly large. Also, stipulating that the graph is a complete one almost certainly takes a step backwards from feasibility. That makes all the nodes have high valence, and it is that high-valence which makes the number of paths explode.

Comment: Yes, I realize that the graph I am considering is not necessarily be a complete one, it could be a few edges like a mesh or grid graph but not a complete graph. In addition, what I also wonder is that which data structure could be feasible for this large network size, whether stack or heap could handle the extreme cases.

Comment: As mentioned, I have used the function that used the stack implementation, so I am not sure that it could be feasible for finding the paths in large networks scale, however, heap implementation is one of the candidacies.

Comment: I found this [source](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/latest/_modules/networkx/algorithms/shortest_paths/generic.html#all_shortest_paths) which supports the function for finding all shortest paths. It might support for large network scales.

Answer (score 0):

Depth-first is the only way to make it scalable at the level you specify, at least until quantum computing gives us infinite processing power.  The number of paths if you have 100% adjacency among all nodes is about the same as the number of atoms in the universe, around 2^120.

Comment: 2^120 seems much too small. If there are 200 nodes on a complete graph then there are over 198! paths between a given pair of nodes, which is already 2^1230

Comment: @JohnColeman you're right - I googled it and pulled the first number that came up, but that was merely for a tiny interesting subset of 5000!